# Exclusive join on has many relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Postgres table where user can have many payment subscriptions and the payment subscriptions are either active or inactive, which is shown through an activated_at and an inactivated_at date field on the payment subscriptions table. I now want to find all the users without active payment subscriptions.

Finding all the users without any payment subscription is easy enough

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN payment_subscriptions ON (payment_subscriptions.user_id = users.id)").where("payment_subscriptions.id IS NULL")
```

I also want to find all the users who only have inactive subscriptions. If I use the same pattern as above I will find all the users who at some point have inactivated their subscription, but there is no guarantee that they do not also have an active subscription.

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN payment_subscriptions ON (payment_subscriptions.user_id = users.id)").where("payment_subscriptions.inactivated_at IS NOT NULL")
```

How do I get the users who have either no subscriptions or no active subscriptions from my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one gives you users without any active subscriptions.

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN payment_subscriptions on (payment_subscriptions.user_id = users.id and payment_subscriptions.inactivated_at is null)").where("payment_subscriptions.id is null")
```

If you want to get only those who have inactive, use also your previous join

I don't know if it possible in rails, but you also can use `not exists` syntax:

```
User.where('
    not exists (
         select *
         from payment_subscriptions as ps
         where ps.user_id = users.id and ps.inactivated_at is not null
    )
')
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much information about how you actually define if a user doesn't currently have a payment subscription but from what I can infer you need to check that payment_subscriptions.inactivated_at isn't null and that payment_subscriptions.id is also null.

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN payment_subscriptions ON (payment_subscriptions.user_id = users.id)").where("payment_subscriptions.inactivated_at IS NOT NULL AND payment_subscriptions.id IS NULL")
```

Comment: This will actually give me all users who either have no subscriptions or at some point have inactivated a subscription. Since users can have several subscriptions it is very possible that they have an active subscription along with inactive subscriptions.